# Quotient Spaces that are $T_0$, and the Quotient Space $x \sim y$ iff $\overline{\{x\}}=\overline{\{y\}}$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space; verify that by letting $xE_0y$ whenever $\overline{ \{ x \} } = \overline{ \{ y \} }$, we define an equivalence relation $E_0$ on $X$ and that $X/E_0$ is a $T_0$-space. Show that if for an equivalence relation $E$ on $X$ the quotient space $X/E$ is a $T_0$-space, than $E_0 \subseteq E$.

*Hint:* The set $\overline{ \{ x \} }$ is a union of equivalence classes of $E_0$.

That it defines an equivalence relation, and that the space is $T_0$ I did already, but for $E_0 \subseteq E$ I tried the hint. Obviously $\overline{ \{ x \} } = \bigcup_{y \in \overline{ \{ x \} }} [y]$.

I am rather clueless how to prove $E_0 \subseteq E$. Suppose $xE_0y$ but it is not the case that $x E y$, then $\overline{ \{ x \} } = \overline{ \{ y \} }$ but $\overline{ \{ [x]_E \} } \ne \overline{ \{ [y]_E \} }$ (in the quotient topoloy $X/E$, where $[x]_E$ denotes the equivalence class in $X/E$) using the fact that in a $T_0$ space $x \ne y \Rightarrow \overline{ \{x\} } \ne \overline{ \{y\} }$. I have a vague feeling that this might be a contradiction because $X/E_0$ and $X/E$ should be structurally equivalent (or homeomorphic) in some sense (i.e. $X/E_0$ might be some "universal" $T_0$ quotient space...) but I have no idea how to make this formal.

After some trial and error I came to the conclusion that if I could prove if $X/E$ is a $T_0$ space, then the projection map $p_E : X \to X/E$ would be a closed map (which I conjecture that it would be true, but can't prove) then it would follow.

Any ideas and further hints for me?

Comment: Since you already mentioned the word "universal", this may be interesting for you: The quotient $X/E_0$ is indeed a universal $T_0$ space with respect to $X$. For if $f$ is a continuous map from $X$ to a $T_0$-space $Y$, then there is a unique continuous map $\tilde f:X/E_0\to Y$ such that $f=\tilde f\circ p$. In the case $f=p_E$ this gives your desired result. In the language of category theory this says that the $T_0$-spaces form a reflective subcategory of the topological spaces :-) There are similar constructions, for competely regular spaces for instance.

Comment: Yes, I stumbled here and there over ideas from category theory and had a vague idea that some universal property might hold here. So thank you for pointing out. Btw is the map $\tilde{f} : X/E_0 \to Y$ a homeomorphism in general?

Comment: No, the map $\tilde f$ need not even be surjective or injective, and if it is bijective it need not be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $[x]_E\ne[y]_E$, then, as $X/E$ is $T_0$, one of the points, say $[x]_E$, has an open neighborhood $U$ avoiding the other one ($[y]_E\notin U$).

As the projection $p:X\to X/E$ is continuous, $p^{-1}(U)$ is open, and $y\notin p^{-1}(U)$, but $x\in p^{-1}(U)$. This ensures that $\overline{\{y\}}\subseteq X\setminus p^{-1}(U)$, in particular $x\notin\overline{\{y\}}$. So $x E_0 y$ cannot hold.

Comment: so simple... thx