# Quotient Space induced by $x \sim y \iff \overline{\{ x \}} = \overline{\{ y \}}$ is $T_0$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

Ok, I've been struggling with the following problem; before I get into it I want to put a disclaimer that I only want a hint, **not** a solution.

Let $X$ be a topological space, consider $\sim$ defined by $x \sim y \iff \overline{\{ x \}} = \overline{\{ y \}}$, show that $X / \sim$ is $T_0$.

I've shown that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, but am really struggling showing $X / \sim$ is $T_0$.

My start: In order to show $X$ is $T_0$ I aim to show that if $\tilde{x} \neq \tilde{y}$ then $\overline{\{\tilde{x}\}} \neq \overline{\{\tilde{y}\}}$ given $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y} \in X / \sim$. I've shown that $\overline{\tilde{x}} = \overline{\{x\}}$ for any $x \in \tilde{x}$ (where the closure is in the sense of the topology on $X$) so that $\overline{\tilde{x}}$ is disjoint from $\overline{\tilde{y}}$ for any distinct $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}$. The issue I keep running into is relating $X$ to $X / \sim$, for example I'm not sure how to use the fact that $\overline{\tilde{x}}$ is disjoint from $\overline{\tilde{y}}$ to show $\overline{\{\tilde{x}\}} \neq \overline{\{\tilde{y}\}}$.

EDIT: I was pretty off I think, but I think I have a better handle on this now.

Put $q$ to be the natural map from $X \to X / \tilde{}$, and let $x,y\in X$ be such that $q(x) \neq q(y)$.

For any $x \in X$ we have $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \} = \operatorname{cl}_X q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right]$ since
$$
x \in q(x) \implies x \in q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right] \implies x \in \operatorname{cl}_X q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right] \implies \operatorname{cl}_X \{x\} \subset \operatorname{cl}_X q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right]
$$
and if $y \in q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right]$ then $\operatorname{cl}_X \{x\} = \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\}$ so $y \in \operatorname{cl}_X \{x\}$ thus $\operatorname{cl}_X q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right] \subset \operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \}$.

Next notice since $q(x) \neq q(y)$ we have $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \} \neq \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$. W.l.o.g. consider $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \} \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \neq \emptyset$ and note that $\exists z \in q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right] \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$, otherwise if $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \supset q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right]$ then $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \supset \operatorname{cl}_X q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right]$, but we have $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \} = \operatorname{cl}_X q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right]$ so we would get $\operatorname{cl}_X \{y\} \supset \operatorname{cl}_X \{x\}$ which tells us $\operatorname{cl}_X \{x\} \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\} = \emptyset$, a contradiction to our assumption. Note also that $z \in q^{-1}\left[ \{ q(x) \} \right] \implies q(z) = q(x)$.

Now I want to show that $q \left[ X - \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \right]$ is open, to do this I will show that 
$$
q^{-1} \left[ q \left[ X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \right] \right] = X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}
$$
First let $w \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\}$ then $q(w) \in q \left[X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\} \right]$ so $w \in q^{-1} \left[ q \left[X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\}\right] \right]$. Next let $w \in q^{-1} \left[ q \left[X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\} \right] \right]$ then $q(w) \in q \left[ X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \right]$ so that $\exists v \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ such that $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ v \} = \operatorname{cl}_X \{ w \}$. Now suppose for contradiction that $w \in \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ then $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ w \} \subset \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ so $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ v \} \subset \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ thus $v \in \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ but we have that $v \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ so we conclude that $w \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$.

Now $q(y) \not\in q\left[ X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \right]$, otherwise this would tell us that $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} = \operatorname{cl}_X \{ v \}$ for some $v \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ so that $v \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ v \}$, a contradiction. Also $q(x) \in q \left[ X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} \right]$ since $z \in X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ and $q(z) = q(x)$. Thus I found an open set containing $q(x)$ but not $q(y)$ so $X / \tilde{}$ is $T_0$.

---

This feels fairly jenky, though, so I'm unsure if I missed something and did something wrong or if I missed something and the proof is much simpler.

Comment: This seems relevant, or even a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443092/quotient-spaces-that-are-t-0-and-the-quotient-space-x-sim-y-iff-overline

Comment: @AsafKaragila note the following comment in there: "That it defines an equivalence relation, and that the space is $T_0$ I did already"

Comment: Oh yeah. You're right. I'll leave my comment up, so other people won't make the same mistake later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $q:X\to X/\!\sim$ be the quotient map. You know that if $q(x)\ne q(y)$, then $$\operatorname{cl}_X\{x\}\ne\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}\;.$$ Without loss of generality there is a point $z\in(\operatorname{cl}_X\{x\})\setminus\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$; note that $q(z)=q(x)$. Show that $q^{-1}\left[q\big[\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}\big]\right]=\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$, and consider the set $q\big[X\setminus\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}\big]$ in $X/\!\sim$.

(If you’re familiar with the term *saturated set* in this context, I’m suggesting that you show that $\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$ is saturated and see what this tells you about its complement.)

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would be courteous enough to explain what’s wrong with the answer, so that I can fix it?

Comment: Just FYI, I didn't downvote, still muddling through details

Comment: @DanZimm: I hope that my changing notation isn’t too distressing; the bars were a bit confusing, and I prefer the $\operatorname{cl}$ notation for closure anyway. I also wanted to emphasize the quotient *map*.

Comment: No problem on notation, I do have a question though, why do you define $z$? Also is there a trick to showing $q^{-1}[q[\operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}]] \subset \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$? I don't see how, given some $w$ such that $q(w) \in q[ \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \} ]$ we get that $w \in \operatorname{cl}_X \{ y \}$ (i.e. how do we know that $w$ isn't in some equivalency class that's in $ q[ \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\} ] \setminus q[ \{y\} ]$)?

Comment: @DanZimm: Let’s postpone the reason for $z$; it may become clear when you get the rest sorted. Suppose that $u\in q^{-1}[q[\operatorname{cl}_X \{y\}]]$; then $q(u)\in q[\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}]$, so $u\sim v$ for some $v\in\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$. Use this to show that $\operatorname{cl}_X\{u\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$.

Comment: @Brian: My guess is that someone confused saturated sets with saturated fats, and thought that you are advocating those, which is generally a bad thing. But I really have no idea why someone would downvote that.

Comment: Aha! This was my issue all along, I believe, I was forgetting closures are closed... (specifically I wasn't realizing that if $x$ is in $\operatorname{cl}_X \tilde{y}$ for some equivalence class $\tilde{y}$ then either $x \in \tilde{y}$ (easy to see) or $\operatorname{cl}_X \tilde{x} \subset \operatorname{cl}_X \tilde{y} \implies \tilde{x} \subset \tilde{y}$, where $\tilde{x}$ is the equivalence class associated to $x$ (which I suppose is equally simple to see, but I was tripping up on this).

Comment: @DanZimm: Yep, that’s the crucial point. In fact you can define a [quasiorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) on $X$ by $x\preceq y$ iff $\operatorname{cl}_X\{x\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$ and show that $x\preceq y\preceq x$ iff $x\sim y$. When you take the quotient, the quasiorder induces a partial order, which is equivalent to saying that the quotient is $T_0$.

Comment: I personally don't see where to go with that last set (at least for now), going to sleep on it and get back to this.

Comment: @DanZimm: Okay. I’ll leave one further hint for now: it’s open.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was guessing it was open (then we can say, putting $A = q[ X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\} ]$, $q(x) \in A$, but $q(y) \not\in A$ so we've shown that there exists an open set containing $q(x)$ and not $q(y)$ making the space $T_0$) but my struggle for finishing this is coming from showing $q[X] \setminus q[\operatorname{cl}_X \{y\}] = q[ X \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \{y\}]$... Hopefully I'll figure it out sooner rather than later ;D

Comment: @DanZimm: If you’re still stuck tomorrow, let me know, and I’ll see if I can push you in the right direction. I will be online at some point, though not until the afternoon EST.

Comment: Ok I think I have everything except seeing why $q(z) = q(x)$ - why can't we have $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ z \} \neq \operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \}$? Couldn't it be the case that $\operatorname{cl}_X \{ x \} \supsetneq \operatorname{cl}_X \{ z \}$?

Comment: I think I solved the issue I commented on above in my post, do you mind looking at what I wrote and telling me if it's correct / if I missed something to make the proof simpler?

Comment: @DanZimm: Commenting on the EDIT: Technically $q(x)$ isn’t a subset of $X$; what you’re calling $\operatorname{cl}_Xq(x)$ is $\operatorname{cl}_Xq^{-1}[\{q(x)\}]$. I understand your usage, but I think that it increases the risk of losing track of what’s where. \\ You can’t assume that $\operatorname{cl}_X\{x\}\supset\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}$, but you can assume that $\operatorname{cl}_X\{x\}\setminus\operatorname{cl}_X\{y\}\ne\varnothing$: the two singleton closures might be disjoint. \\ Otherwise it looks okay.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed the issues, do you mind checking once again? This feels awfully circuitous, is there a more direct, simpler proof that you can see?

Comment: @DanZimm: Looks okay, though I admit that I just took a quick look at the parts in question. I don’t think that the argument is very circuitous: you’re showing pretty directly that if $q(x)\ne q(y)$, then at least one of $q(x)$ and $q(y)$ can be separated from the other. What make it look more roundabout than it really is are the details involved in dealing with the quotient topology, and with more experience you would probably omit some of those as being obvious (or at least very familiar). At any rate this was the first approach that occurred to me, though my write-up would be shorter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @DanZimm: My pleasure!